# Inserting Image ruins the frame layout

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am starting using wx for my Python application and I run in a small problem when trying to include an image in a Frame.

I compiled this into a simple example. 
What I dont understand is that I have no problem of layout when replacing my image by text. Whe I try entering the image, the layout gets ruined.

Here is my layout with text, that contains only two elements. The logo, and the title of the application

[image: layout with text]

And here is what I got when trying to insert the logo :

[image: layout with image]

For some reason, the layout is ruined, and the title is placed on top left corner (and we can't see it anymore.)

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx

class IvolutionWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 100))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        # Creating the title layout
        title = self.setup_titlelayout()

        # Creating the main grid
        maingrid = self.setup_maingrid(title)
        self.panel.SetSizer(maingrid)
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.Show(True)

    def setup_titlelayout(self):
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)  # used to contain logo part and text part
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  # used to separate title and one-liner
        logobox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        wx_logo = wx.EmptyBitmap(1, 1)  # Create a bitmap container object.
        wx_logo.LoadFile("ivolution/data/media/vitruve_50.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)  # Load it with a file image.

        #logo = wx.StaticBitmap(self, 1, wx_logo)
        logo = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Logo Here")  # Change for proper logo
        title = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Ivolution")

        logobox.Add(logo)
        vbox.Add(title, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)

        hbox.Add(logobox, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)
        hbox.Add(vbox, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)

        return hbox

    def setup_maingrid(self, title):
        maingrid = wx.FlexGridSizer(4, 1, vgap=0, hgap=0)
        maingrid.Add(title)
        return maingrid

    def on_exit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)  # Close the frame.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = IvolutionWindow(None, "Ivolution")
    app.MainLoop()  # Runs application
```

It should run on any computer if you change the location of the image to a correct one.

The only line of code changing between the two pictures is here :

```
#logo = wx.StaticBitmap(self, 1, wx_logo)

logo = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Logo Here")  # Change for proper logo
```

I am new with wxPython, so I guess there is something obvious here, but I can't find what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same parent for the StaticText and the StaticBitmap if you want the same effect.
Thus use:

```
logo = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, 1, wx_logo)
```

Comment: And obvious indeed it was. Thank you very much !